# Testing that HTTP-request is not made in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fakeweb

What is the easiest way to test if HTTP-request is not made?

Say, I want my application NOT to send an API call to a remote server, if the user doesn't supply a username.

What RSpec test should I write in my Rails app to test that HTTP-request is never made?
Can fakeweb help me somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably try [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).
It allows you to check the number of times some url was requested.

```
assert_requested :post, "http://www.example.com", :times => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Say we have the following code that makes a conditional request to GitHub's API.

```
if condition
  user = Octokit.user 'dideler'
end
```

Using RSpec, you can test that the object doesn't receive the message for the method call.

```
expect(Octokit).to_not receive(:user)
```

If it passes, that means the request wasn't made.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking. You just want to error check to see if a request sent or valid.

If username != blank --> api call else return 'you did not input a username'.

Or you can use the api's return data to check if the request was valid.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I need to make my question more clear. What RSpec test should I write in my Rails app to test that HTTP-request is never made? I've updated my question as well.